# jQuery - Adding values of multiple inputs together & display in another input

Tags: jquery

I have some code, that to my mind, should be finding all classes '.stock-input', adding their values together, and displaying that value in the id #pStockQuantity, I can't see why I'm getting the result NaN.

JS:

```
$('.stock-input').keyup(function() {
    var stockTemp = parseInt(0);
    $('.stock-input').each(function() {
        stockTemp = parseInt(stockTemp) + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#pStockQuantity').val(stockTemp);
});
```

Comment: `console.log(stockTemp)` will tell you what you're getting. On a side note, since stockTemp is already an integer you can just do `stockTemp += parseInt($(this).val())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will come if a textfield has a non numeric value

```
$('.stock-input').keyup(function () {
    var stockTemp = 0;
    $('.stock-input').each(function () {
        stockTemp += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });
    $('#pStockQuantity').val(stockTemp);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ha0nvk4r/)